# Managing Contact Collections

Tags: c#, wpf, email

I have a WPF/MVVM form that contains sections for managing Recipient Contacts, CC Contacts and BCC Contacts.

Each of the three sections has buttons/ICommands for 'Add', 'Clear', 'Previous' and 'Next' that move through the collection of objects.

I'm trying to work out how I can remove the repeated code.

I wire up the commands in my constructor:

```
        this.AddressBookRecipientCommand = new GenericCommand(AddressBookRecipientPressed);
        this.ClearRecipientCommand = new GenericCommand(ClearRecipientPressed, CanClearRecipient);
        this.NextRecipientCommand = new GenericCommand(NextRecipientPressed, CanPressNextRecipient);
        this.PrevRecipientCommand = new GenericCommand(PrevRecipientPressed, CanPressPrevRecipient);
        this.AddressBookCCCommand = new GenericCommand(AddressBookCCPressed);
        this.ClearCCCommand = new GenericCommand(ClearCCPressed, CanClearCC);
        this.NextCCCommand = new GenericCommand(NextCCPressed, CanPressNextCC);
        this.PrevCCCommand = new GenericCommand(PrevCCPressed, CanPressPrevCC);
        this.AddressBookBCCCommand = new GenericCommand(AddressBookBCCPressed);
        this.ClearBCCCommand = new GenericCommand(ClearBCCPressed, CanClearBCC);
        this.NextBCCCommand = new GenericCommand(NextBCCPressed, CanPressNextBCC);
        this.PrevBCCCommand = new GenericCommand(PrevBCCPressed, CanPressPrevBCC);
```

Then I have the various command code:

```
    public ICommand AddressBookRecipientCommand { get; set; }
    public void AddressBookRecipientPressed()
    {
        this.Recipient = this.Details.Recipients.ReplaceAndReturn(this.Recipient, this.Outlook.GetContact());
    }

    public ICommand PrevRecipientCommand { get; set; }
    public bool CanPressPrevRecipient()
    {
        return Details.Recipients.IndexOf(Recipient) != 0;
    }
    public void PrevRecipientPressed()
    {
        int i = Details.Recipients.IndexOf(Recipient);
        Recipient = Details.Recipients[i - 1];
    }

    public ICommand NextRecipientCommand { get; set; }
    public bool CanPressNextRecipient()
    {
        return !Recipient.IsNullOrEmpty() && Details.Recipients.IndexOf(Recipient) != MaxRecipients;
    }
    public void NextRecipientPressed()
    {
        if (Details.Recipients.IndexOf(Recipient) + 1 == Details.Recipients.Count)
        {
            Recipient = new Contact();
            Details.Recipients.Add(Recipient);
        }
        else
        {
            int i = Details.Recipients.IndexOf(Recipient);
            Recipient = Details.Recipients[i + 1];
        }
    }

    public ICommand ClearRecipientCommand { get; set; }
    public bool CanClearRecipient()
    {
        return !Recipient.IsNullOrEmpty();
    }
    public void ClearRecipientPressed()
    {
        int i = this.Details.Recipients.IndexOf(this.Recipient);
        if (i + 1 == this.Details.Recipients.Count)
            this.Recipient.Clear();
        else
        {
            this.Details.Recipients.Remove(this.Recipient);
            this.Recipient = this.Details.Recipients[i];
        }
    }
```

This code is repeated for CC and BCC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're doing, I think what you need is a `UserControl` that encapsulates some `AddressBookCommand`, `ClearCommand`, `NextCommand` and `PreviousCommand` commands.

Your main *view* would have 3 instances of that control, one for each field ("To", "CC", "BCC"), and each would have its own *data context*, some `IList<Contact>` I'd guess.

Also you're not showing your entire class so it's hard to tell, but since you mention MVVM I believe a lot of this code belongs in a *ViewModel* class, not in the *View*'s code-behind; the XAML markup uses *DataBinding* markup extensions to bind visual element properties to properties in the *ViewModel* - the Window's `DataContext` property is set to the instance of the *ViewModel* class.

The reason I mention this, is because ideally in MVVM the *View* should only be caring for *presentation* concerns, which clearly `Details.Recipients.Add(Recipient);` isn't.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't used UserControls before. I'll take a look.
Yes, the code above is from the ViewModel.